# Gedit drag and drop code

Tags: gedit, html

I am using Gedit(3.4.1) and use it to edit my website with it.
and usually when i change/remove/edit my website, i have to change all of my html
pages to make it look the same, layout wise and,
right now i am removing some code, and pasting another in it.

My question is. can i have save that code as a snippet or such??? i want to be able to drop that code onto gedit, and possibly apply that to all over my opened HTML pages

Answer (score 2):

Sir, you have your priorities wrong. Take care of your layout, learn and use CSS, ruby, php even, and you will not have to edit each and single page.

P.S. And for batch modifications of text files use awk, sed, perl, python or a multitude of other tools that can do the job more reliably than any GUI interface. For example, use a templating system in the programming language of your choice or with ad hoc bash scripts taking advantage of the power of command line.

Comment: I sayed layout but meant plugins like Ubuntu countdown banner/sociaal media sharing plugins(apologize ) for instance i am adding shareaholic sexybookmarks (G+/fb/twitter/reddit) and i have to paste it in all my pages

Comment: So? Use server side includes, php, ruby. If you can but upload static html files to a server, then create templates and process them with perl, python or ad hoc scripts.

Comment: hhhmmm, perl/python/ad hoc... don't know those programming language's?

Comment: do you have any good tutorials, On what u are talking about!?